# R: VAR model accuracy error

Tags: r, statistics, arguments

I have two questions. (**Note: The first part of the question has been resolved in the comments below**)

1. Firstly, I'm trying to determine the Mean Absolute Error of a VAR forecast based on [this tutorial](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/tscvexample/) by Rob Hyndman and am getting the following error message:

   ```
   Error in `-.default`(fcast[['mean']], dxnext) :
     non-numeric argument to binary operator
   ```

   I believe I have managed to track it down to the output of VAR which is non numerical, and seems to be causing the problem.

   Is there a workaround?
2. Secondly, this code needs to work for bi and multivariate models and as such I have doubts as to whether I should use the length of `dx` for `n` as the tutorial suggests, or the length of one of the variables, as this is the length that represents the given time frame. The problem lies in the length of `dx` and how it is handled in the loop for a given forecast length (12 in this case). Any input would be appreciated.

Below is the code with sample data and the packages required so the error can be replicated.

```
require("forecast")
require("vars")

x <- rnorm(70)
y <- rnorm(70)

dx <- cbind(x,y)
dx <- as.ts(dx)

# Forecast Accuracy
k <- 58 # data length less forecast horison (as minimum)
n <- length(dx)
mae <- matrix(NA, n-k, 12)
st <- tsp(dx)[1]+(k-2)/12

for (i in 1:(n-k)) {
 dxshort <- window(dx, end=st+i/12)
 dxnext <- window(dx, start=st + (i+1)/12, end=st+(i+12)/12)
 fit <- VAR(dxshort, p = 2)
 fcast <- forecast(fit, h = 12)
 mae[i,1:length(dxnext)] <- abs(fcast[['mean']] - dxnext)
}

plot(1:12, colMeans(mae,na.rm = TRUE), type = "1", Col = 2, xlab = "horizon", ylab = "MAE")
```

**EDIT**

The following code appears to resolve the above problem, but I am still having issues with regards to how the output is handled.

My gut feeling is that it only records the last iteration of the loop, and that that the forecast horizon of that iteration extends into the future (beyond the scope of the available data).

As is explained partially in the link I provided above, the code attempts to run models based on the blue data (see example picture below) and forecast the red data set, record the mean error for each forecast horizon, store that in a data frame and finally take the mean average error of all the iterations.

[image: CV]

```
library(forecast)
library(vars)
library(plyr)

x <- rnorm(70)
y <- rnorm(70)

dx <- cbind(x,y)
dx <- as.ts(dx)

# Forecast Accuracy
j = 12  #Forecast horizon
k = nrow(dx)-j #length of minimum training set

prediction <- data.frame()
actual <- data.frame()

for (i in j) { 
  trainingset <- window(dx, end = k+i-1)
  testset <- window(dx, start = k-j+i+1, end = k+j)
  fit <- VAR(trainingset, p = 3)                       
  fcast <- forecast(fit, h = j)
  fcastmean <- do.call('cbind', fcast[['mean']])
  fcastmean <- as.data.frame(fcastmean)

  prediction <- rbind(fcastmean)
  actual <- rbind(as.data.frame(testset[,1]))
}

# add predictions and actual values
result <- cbind(prediction[,1], actual)
names(result) <- c("Predicted", "Actual")
result$Difference <- abs(result$Actual - result$Predicted)
```

Comment: `fcast[['mean']]` returns `NA` (after change to `fcast <- predict(fit, n.ahead = 12)`)

Comment: @HubertL thanks, I did notice that. It seems quite clear that the above code is flawed... But not sure how exactly.

Comment: `fcast[['mean']]` is of class `list`, which is not a numeric type. This is the source of your first error. Convert it to something useful, like a multivariate time series: `do.call('cbind', fcast[['mean']])`.

Comment: @attitude_stool Thanks a lot for that! that worked perfectly. Got any idea on how to deal with the second part of the question? The original code only took regression models with one variable, so while the time period is only 70 months, `dx` = 140...

Comment: @HubertL Please see the latest edit. Any help would be extremely appreciated!